# How to Join tables only where table1.column2 - table2.column3 > 0 (or !=0) Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm still a novice to sql, using Postgres. i have two tables:

table request

| order_id | amount_requested |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 5 |
| 25 | 8 |
| 12 | 1 |

table response

| order_id | amount_added |
| --- | --- |
| 51 | 5 |
| 25 | 4 |
| 12 | 0 |

I am trying to get only the order_id's where the response.amount_added is less than the request.amount_requested, and add a column with the difference. So in this case the result would be:

| order_id | amount_requested | amount_added | amount_remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 8 | 4 | 4 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

order_id 51 wasn't in the result (desired outcome), because amount requested(5) was not less than the amount_added.

The query I am trying does not return any rows, even when the amount_request > amount_added

```
I tried-


    SELECT request.order_id, 
           request.amount_requested, 
           response.amount_inserted, 
           request.amount_requested - response.amount_added as amount_remaining 
    FROM request 
    INNER JOIN response
    ON request.order_id = response.order_id
    WHERE request.amount_requested > response.amount_added




**This query output no rows.**
```

However I know it's *mostly* working, because if I remove

```
    WHERE request.to_disp > response.amount_added
```

It does show the results! HOWEVER, it includes the rows that don't have a remainder:

| order_id | amount_requested | amount_added | amount_remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51 | 5 | 5 | 0 -- *Don't want this row!* |
| 25 | 8 | 4 | 4 |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

```
So, I'd like to only include rows that either :

have amount_remaining != 0
request.amount_requested > response.amount_added
request.amount_requested - response.amount_added> 0
request.amount_requested - response.amount_added!= 0
```

Any of those conditions should work, as the amount_added will never be larger than the amount requested

I am not sure why the WHERE condition is not working properly. Thank you for any help!

Comment: In this last code block (myb choose other formatting) describing what you'd like to have, you're writing `response.amount_inserted` instead of `...added`. Plus you might leave this first point about `!= 0` out because it is covered by the line `request.amount_requested - response.amount_added > 0`. And remove the last two lines because they're also covered by the second line. Can't we just take `request.amount_requested > response.amount_added` as the one and only condition we need?

Comment: Oh! thanks I edited it to amount_added. Yes, >, > 0 and !=0 is reduntant, I'm just not sure which is preferred. The main issue is that the WHERE condition isn't working

Comment: No idea why it doesn't work for you, but I've recreated your issue here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hR2h8BUPefa2JrBZX3etVp/0 and https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNhiv6RsKyTdAjLkw9YXEy/1. They seem to work fine for me, could you provide more details

Comment: @Ianis Works, but I would avoid natural joins. They are obscure and error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the wanted result using a query like this

```
SELECT *, amount_requested - amount_added AS remaining 
FROM response NATURAL JOIN request
WHERE amount_requested > amount_added
```

To explain this in more detail since OP is rather new.

The query will run these operations in the following order,

1. It will compute the to be processed table in the `FROM` clause
2. It will weed out any values that violate the `WHERE` clause
3. It will compute the `SELECT` clause

**FROM**: The result of `response NATURAL JOIN request` is equivalent to doing a `CROSS JOIN` (Cartesian Product) and then selecting only the tuples where the attributes with matching names are equal, to put this into SQL terms, this query will have an equivalent result

```
SELECT * 
FROM response, request
WHERE response.order_id = request.order_id
```

With one difference from the above query will have 4 attributes `response.order_id, amount_added, request.order_id, amount_requested` While `NATURAL JOIN` will merge response.order_id with request.order_id.

**WHERE**: In our query tuples will just remove any rows where `amount_requested > amount_added` as might be expected aka where amount_requested - amount_added > 0

**SELECT**: Only now will select values be computed, at this point our working table will look like this

| order_id | amount_added | amount_requested |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 0 | 1 |
| 25 | 4 | 8 |

We can then just select all the preexisting attributes with the `*` Wild card, and add another attributes that is the remaining amount to be paid (I'm assuming)

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hR2h8BUPefa2JrBZX3etVp/0) is a database fiddle that showcases the query and that you can play with, and [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNhiv6RsKyTdAjLkw9YXEy/1) is another one with a `INNER JOIN` since you said you'd like to avoid natural joins

Answer (score -1):

You can use a derived table:

```
select * from (
    select t1.order_id,(t1.amount_requested - t2.amount_added) as amount_remaining 
    from request t1 join response t2 on t1.order_id=t2.order_id ) as d where d.amount_remaining > 0
```

Here is the test :)

Comment: No, you cannot do that, you would not be able to see the calculated select value in the where clause. Since the where clause is computed first

Comment: Yes but this is not a aggregate function, you can reference those in group by/having clauses, try your solution out

Comment: @Ianis true you need having for postgres. Still this can be wrapped in one more select and it will work :D As I said in the Exclaimer I can not guarantee the syntax, just the aproach.  But Select from Select will work with this query :P

Comment: @Ianis. are you so sure ? Test this then :)

Comment: Yes the new edited answer is correct but why would you do that? Its harder to read (and should in theory be more costly) also the link you sent was of my original solution (?) Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something you are saying, in which case I would love to hear your idea. Also I understand language might be a barrier so feel free to answer in Russian as I can read it mostly fine.